# Who hid the collection of ancient Jedi texts in the millenium falcon? Did Yoda know about them when he destroyed the tree?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In the film's close moment we can see that Rey possesses the books, as they are stowed away on the Millennium Falcon. But did she put them there?

Did Yoda know something about it? And why didn't anyone tell Luke about them?

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176345/58193).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot yes, sorry i don't saw this question when i search about the jedis text.

Comment: Yoda knew and Yoda told Luke. "There is nothing in there that girl doesn't already possess" is more or less a direct quote.